# Program to count number of times a character appear in file(case insensitive)

Tags: c

executed this code in an online editor.but always getting `File 'test.txt' has 0 instances of letter 'r'`.what to do??`File 'test.txt' has 99 instances of letter'r'`.This is the expected   output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    int d=0;
    char c;
    char ch,ck;
    char b[100];
    printf("Enter the file name\n");
    scanf("%19s",b);
    fptr=fopen(b,"r");
    printf("Enter the character to be counted\n");
    scanf(" %c",&c);
    c=toupper(c);
    if(fptr==NULL)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
    while((ck=fgetc(fptr))!=EOF)
    {
        ch=toupper(ck);
        if(c==ch||c==ck)
            ++d;
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    printf("File '%s' has %d instances of letter '%c'.",b,d,c);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int`, so `ck` should also be an `int`.

Comment: Why `19` here `scanf("%19s",b);` when `b` can hold a maximum of 99 characters, +1 for the NUL-terminator? BTW, post the contents of `test.txt`.

Comment: Besides the issue with `ck` the code looks good.

Comment: It works for me. I tested it. Now in the process of prettifying it.

Comment: How did you get `File 'test.txt' has 0 instances of letter 'r'` as the output? It should've been `File 'test.txt' has 0 instances of letter 'R'`. Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problems:

1. `ck` should be an `int`, not a `char` as [@alk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk) [has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536416/program-to-count-number-of-times-a-character-appear-in-filecase-insensitive#comment52930875_32536416) because `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`.
2. As per the title, you want a case insensitive comparision. Your code does not do that. The solution is that this:

   ```
   if(c==ch||c==ck)
   ```

   needs to be

   ```
   if(c == ch || (tolower(c)) == ck) /* Compare upper with upper, lower with lower */
   ```

Comment: This is **C**, not **C++**. Use `tolower(c)` instead of `c.tolower()`.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it. It works fine. I can't detect your problem without you providing the test file it fails on. As far as I am concerned, it does what it is supposed to do - it counts the number of times specified character appears (case-insensitive) in specified file. Here's your prettified version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> /* strlen */
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH 100

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* Variables */
    FILE *file = NULL;
    int count = 0, file_char;
    char target_char, filename[MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH];
    /* Getting filename */
    printf("Enter the file name: ");
    fgets(filename, MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH, stdin);
    /* Removing newline at the end of input */
    size_t filename_len = strlen(filename);
    if(filename_len > 0 && filename[filename_len - 1] == '\n') {
        filename[filename_len - 1] = '\0'; }
    /* Opening file */
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(file == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    /* Getting character to count */
    printf("Enter the character to be counted: ");
    scanf(" %c", &target_char);
    target_char = toupper(target_char);
    /* Counting characters */
    while((file_char = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        file_char = toupper(file_char);
        if(target_char == file_char) ++count; }
    /* Reporting finds */
    printf("File '%s' has %d instances of letter '%c'.",
           filename, count, target_char);
    /* Exiting */
    fclose(file);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; }
```

Comment: thank u all..the code is working now..the problem is file 'test.txt' satisfies the null condition.i check it for other files it works good